# assign a copy of a function to a var

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to define a function and then assign copies of the function to different vars?

This is essentially how far I've got...

```
function add(x, y){
   return x + y;
}

var function1 = new add()
var function2 = new add()
```

This doesn't seem to work as it's trying to run the add function each time.  The same goes for

```
var function1 = new function add()
```

Do I need to be using prototype in some way or am I looking at it in the wrong way?

Comment: you can do it like this--  `var function1 = add;  function1();`

Comment: Why would you want to _copy_ a function?

Comment: Why do you need a copy of the function? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are evaluating the function. To assign the function itself to a variable, use

```
var function1 = add;
var function2 = add;
```

However, it's not quite clear why you want to copy the function.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick

```
var function1 = add;
var function2 = add;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your just trying to create references to the function just make this modification

```
function add(x, y){
  return x + y;
}

var function1 = add;
var function2 = add;
```

After which you are able to call the functions like this.

```
function1(10,11);

function2(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function in Javascript is an object as any other.

You can create many references to the same function and store them for example in an array

```
function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

var v = [add, add, add, add];

alert(v[3](33, 9)); // Will show 42
```

The only "magic" thing happens when you call a function getting it from an object member lookup

```
x = {};
x.f = add;
x.f(12, 3);  // Returns 15
```

the "strange" thing that will happen is that `this` inside the function when called that way will be the object, and not the global `window` object as it happens when you call a function directly.

This also means that, confusingly enough,

```
x.f(z);
```

is not the same as

```
[x.f][0](z);
```

or as

```
var ff = x.f;
ff(z);
```

because in the first case `this` will be `x`, in the second case `this` will be the array instead and in the third case it will be the global `window` object.